# how can I add dependencies stored in Spring Plugins Repository with Gradle?

Tags: gradle, dependencies, maven-central

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.swagger2markup/swagger2markup

I'm using Swagger2Markup 1.3.4, and this dependency needs paleo-core:0.14.0, located at jcenter(). As you know, jcenter is deprecated for many reasons.

so I tried to downgrading of Swagger2Markup to 1.3.3, because it needs paleo-core 0.11.0, stored at Spring plugins Repository.

I added my code at `build.gradle`:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/'}
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

but it does not work, with endless build process (guess connection timeout or can not find in url)
[image]

I'm wondering that is the code wrote properly.

thank u for reading :)

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, I didn't know the fact that when using Spring Plugins Repository authentication needs with username & password. thanks!